# Pass $title to view

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to understand Laravel 4:

\controllers\catalogs.php

```
class Catalogs_Controller extends BaseController {
  public function get_index(){
    return View::make('catalogs')->with('title', 'Catalog - Home');
  }
}
```

routes.php

```
 Route::get('/', array('as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'catalogs@index'));
```

\views\layouts\default.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ $title }}</title>
.....
</html>
```

\view\catalogs\index.blade.php

```
 @extends('layouts.default')
 @section('content')
Home Page
 @endsection
```

But I have an error:
"Class catalogs does not exist".
Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically everything is wrong, including the name of the files. the following solution

```
// app/controllers/CatalogsController.php

class CatalogsController extends BaseController {
  public function get_index(){
    return View::make('catalogs/index')->with('title', 'Catalog - Home');
  }
}

// app/routes.php
Route::get('/', array('as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'CatalogsController@get_index'));


// app/views/layouts/default.blade.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ $title }}</title>
.....
</html>


// app/view/catalogs/index.blade.php

@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    Home Page
@endsection
```

now you must run the command `composer dump-autoload`

see this: http://laravel.com/docs/quick

Comment: if the problem is resolved, mas my answer to accept (arrow green in left)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with Laravel, but my guess is that the connection between class and filename is case-sensitive, so try to change

```
\controllers\catalogs.php
```

to

```
\controllers\Catalogs.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also not familiar with Lara but I think your problem is on line 3 of `return View::make('catalogs')->with('title', 'Catalog - Home');`

Try to use `return View::make('Catalogs')->with('title', 'Catalog - Home');`

Cheers...